# Load data when webservices starts

Tags: sql-server, web-services, dotnetnuke

i have a scenario where i have to load data from SQL server when i start running a web service. Later i have to use this data for my application, instead of accessing it every time from Database. In addition to this this data should be refreshed every one hour without affecting the website operation on the back end.If any of you has came across such scenario please let me know the solution. By the way i am using asp.net web services, SQL server database, and DNN for my front end.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Global Asax,Application start event you can load all your data in the Dataset.
And by using Sql Cache dependency, You can refresh the data for each hour.But loading the 
Entire data is not advisable.By making so you memory will be full.There will
be Performance degrade.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14976/ASP-NET-Caching-Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Pre-loading all of your data is not a good practice because the database loses its purpose then. It’s probably ok for some data that is very rarely updated but needed very frequently but most definitely not for all the data you have in database.

As for the loading of data you can use app start event as others have already suggested.

Regarding caching – use Application object to make this data available to all parts of application and add a proprety to it that will keep the time of the last update. Then just create separate service that will check the last update time every X minutes and refresh the data when the time comes.